# Nested jQuery loops - how can this be better accomplished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, nested-loops

I'm sprucing up a library I inherited and came across this little tidbit:

```
queries = urlParams.query.split("&");

// Split URL Queries
$.each(queries, function (i, val) {
    val = val.split("=");
    args[val[0]] = val[1];  //Assign query args into args object using their name (ie: test=123) as the key
});

// Loop through arguments
$.each(args, function (i, val) {
// Loop through affiliates to compare url arguments against those of the affiliates
    $.each(self.affiliates, function (inc, value) {
        if (value.urlTag === i) {
        self.setAffiliateCookies(i, val, 1);    //Set affiliate cookies
            gotAff = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The gist of what's happening above is that it is parsing the querystring and breaking up the elements into key-value pairs. Easy enough.

What happens after that is that it loops over that new array and then tests to see if the value of `args` exists in the object literal value of `self.affiliates.urlTag`. If so, it sets a cookie, sets `gotAff` to true, and then returns false to kill the `$.each`.

Something about this doesn't seem very efficient to me. I've been playing with a recursive function and I'm not quite there, and I'm not sure if I'm going down the wrong path. I'm not sure that killing the `$.each` with a return false is the most efficient method either.

Any thoughts? Any tips? This sort of pattern is repeated in multiple places and I'd love to know how better to accomplish it.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `val = val.split("=");` doesn't always give you the correct value since `?key=value=abc&key2=123` is still valid. Although in most cases it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the data structures correctly this might be a little cleaner:

```
$.each(self.affiliates, function (inc, value) {
    if (args.hasOwnProperty(value.urlTag)) {
        self.setAffiliateCookies(value.urlTag, args[value.urlTag], 1);    //Set affiliate cookies
        gotAff = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that no matter what it is an n² operation, because you have to go through each argument, and see if it is present in a list. The best you could do in this case is somehow clarify the code, but I'm not really sure you have the correct functions to do that within jQuery.

As an example, here's how I would do it in MooTools:

```
// Create array of affiliate URL tags.
var affiliateURLs = self.affiliates.map(function(affiliate) {
    return affiliate.urlTag;
});

// Filter args list to those with affiliates.
// This is the n² part.
var matchedArgs = Object.filter(args, function(arg, argURL) {
    return affiliateURLs.contains(argURL);
});

// Create cookie for each matched arg.
Object.each(matchedArgs, function(arg, argURL) {
    self.setAffiliateCookies(argURL, arg, 1);
});

// Note that gotAff is simply
// (Object.getLength(matchedArgs) > 0)
```